# Error while merging PDF document using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

Currently, I'm getting

> java.io.IOException: Expected string, found
> COSDictionary{COSName{ID}:COSString{node00001218};COSName{K}:....

I'm using the below code to merge pdfs and the version of PDFBox is 2.0.24.

```java
PDFMergerUtility merger = new PDFMergerUtility();
Path mergedTempFile = Files.createTempFile("merge_", ".pdf");
merger.setDestinationFileName(mergedTempFile.toString());
merger.addSource(new File("D://1.pdf"));
merger.addSource(new File("D://2.pdf"));
merger.mergeDocuments(null);
```

I've also executed the same code with the latest version of PDFBox 3.0.0-alpha2 but the error was not resolved.

Please refer below stack trace for this error.

```
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDNameTreeNode.getNames(PDNameTreeNode.java:272)
at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility.getIDTreeAsMap(PDFMergerUtility.java:1122)
at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility.getIDTreeAsMap(PDFMergerUtility.java:1137)
at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility.mergeIDTree(PDFMergerUtility.java:1094)
at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility.appendDocument(PDFMergerUtility.java:879)
at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility.legacyMergeDocuments(PDFMergerUtility.java:461)
at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility.mergeDocuments(PDFMergerUtility.java:355)
at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility.mergeDocuments(PDFMergerUtility.java:339)
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: That sounds like a pdf with errors.

Comment: Stack trace missing

Comment: Hello @mkl, i've added stack trace for the same, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello @tilman, i've added stack trace for the same, thanks in advance.

Comment: There is an incorrect element in a name tree. A key must be a string, and not a dictionary. Most likely an broken PDF. You can't merge that one. Maybe open it with Adobe Reader and save it and try again, maybe Adobe can "repair" it. However I suspect there are more problems with it.

Comment: Darshan - Like Tilman said, your PDF appears to have an error in its structure tree. If you want a more detailed analysis, please share the PDF. --- @Tilman - it is nice that the `PDFMergerUtility` tries to consider more and more document-level information related to the copied pages; apparently, though, this makes that utility more fragile, more susceptible to errors in the source files. An option might be to make copying these extras optional by providing some switches.

Comment: I'm reluctant to offer such option because this would encourage people to ignore the structure tree, which is useful for screen readers. @darshan you can do this after opening the document: `document.getDocumentCatalog().setStructureTreeRoot(null)` and save it.